Autocomplete drop down from DataTable source
Having an issue with a drop down field on a web form.  It's getting its values from a SQL database via a stored procedure on the page load.  The values come in as a DataTable, and then populated the drop down field using a data bind.  It's worked fine until recently.  Now when you click the drop down, it does nothing, and eventually you get a "page not responding" pop up.  The list of values has grown to over 28k.  I believe this is causing the issue because I've successfully tested it with a smaller list of values.
I'm thinking the best solution is using the Autocomplete functionality, but I've never worked with this.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Do I still initially set a DataTable with the values coming from the SQL dB?  Can I do an Autocomplete off a DataTable?  Should I create a hidden field to hold the 28k choices, and have the AutoComplete get it's choices from the hidden field?  These are just some of the questions I've been wondering about.
Thx.

use the pagination concept on search input using scroll
